# In Monopoly, what happens if we run out of houses and/or hotels?

Tags: monopoly

How the game proceeds after all the properties, houses and hotels already bought?

Comment: It is unclear if you are asking a question about the rules, or about what will practically happen in such a situation.. can you clarify?

Comment: You proceed as normal, rolling the dice, moving, paying rent and, importantly, selling off houses to pay rent as needed. If the  properties are evenly owned, it may take quite a while for luck of the dice to kick one of the players into having to sell, but it should eventually happen.

Answer (score 5):

Building shortages are part of the strategy of the game and it is intended that players might not be able to buy houses because of a lack of them in the bank. It is also intended that when a player has to sell a hotel they also have to sell all all houses as well if there are not enough in the bank.

> BUILDING SHORTAGES
>   When the Bank has no houses to sell,
>   players wishing to build must wait for some player to return or sell
>   his/her houses to the Bank before building. If there are a limited
>   number of houses and hotels available and two or more players wish
>   to buy more than the Bank has, the houses or hotels must be sold at
>   auction to the highest bidder.